# Why can't I set a "can_place_on" tag on my items?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I did some research and I learned that:

```
/give @p lever 1 0 {"minecraft:can_place_on":{"blocks":["red_concrete"]}}
```

works for people but not for me. The command block output says **component 'minecraft:can_place_on' could not be updated**. What is the issue here?

Answer (score 1):

`red_concrete` is not a valid block ID name. All the different colours of concrete are grouped under one block ID, `concrete`. Because `can_place_on` does not support a Tile ID (which sets the type of block, in this case the colour of concrete), you cannot set a specific colour to allow placing on, only ALL concrete, or NO concrete.